# Solving system linear equation of small matrices via Cramer's rule has large numerical error

Tags: c++, lapack, determinants, linear-equation

I made the observation that when I solve a system of linear equation via the Cramer's rule (quotient of two determinants) of matrices of order N < 10, then I get quite a large residual error compared to LAPACK solution.

Here is an example:

```
float B00[36] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {127.3611, -46.75962, 62.8739, -9.175959,   27.23792, 1.395347, 
                                            -46.75962,   841.5496, 406.2475, -119.3715, -33.60108, 6.269638, 
                                            62.8739,    406.2475,  1302.981, -542.8405,  95.03378, 42.77704, 
                                            -9.175959, -119.3715, -542.8405, 434.3342,   34.96918, -33.74546, 
                                            27.23792,  -33.60108,  95.03378, 34.96918,   59.10199, -1.880791, 
                                            1.395347,   6.269638,  42.77704, -33.74546, -1.880791, 2.650853};

float c00[6] __attribute__((aligned(16))) = {-0.102149, -5.76615, -17.02828, 12.47396, 1.158018, -0.9571021};
```

Now *linsolv*ing this, yields for LAPACK (from Intel MKL):

`x = [-0.000314947
      -0.000589154
      -0.00587876
       0.0184799
       0.01738
      -0.0170484]`

and the Cramer's rule (own implementation) yields:

`x = [-0.000314933
      -0.000798058
      -0.00587888
       0.0184808
       0.017381
      -0.0170508]`

Note `x[1]` difference.

I can guarantee that the determinant calculation of mine is correct. Has anyone made a similar observation or can tell something about this?

Comment: More info. What algorithm did you use to compute the determinants?

Comment: have you tried to use `long double` for the internal computations in your algorithm?

Comment: The determinant calculation is based on naive ```det3``` calculations where the initial matrix is broken down in blocks. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant for reference. Also, I have not tried out with ```double```. Will try so however.

Comment: Do you mean the Laplace formula?

Comment: My guess is that the double precision will solve the problem. Indeed, `float` are only 6 digit precise. The precision of the result `x` is limited by the precision of the rhs `b` and the condition number of the matrix `A`, whatever the solver is. See http://terpconnect.umd.edu/~petersd/460/linsysterrn.pdf for instance. Hence, if the condition number of your matrix is about 100 (which is possible...), the relative error on `x` is 100 times the relative error on the rhs ... And that's for a given norm: individual terms of `x` can feature a larger relative error. Had you used `double` (13 digits)

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan I believe your problem lies in the determinant implementation you choose. If it's like I said the Laplace formula, then you have to perform about `n!` addition and a lot of multiplications which means that when computing the determinant of a marix sized 10x10 you are actually performing more than one million floating point operations. Your 6x6 case is about 1000 floating point operations per determinant which may lead to such an error. Try the LU decomposition or the Gauss method.

Comment: @francis and @AdrianJałoszewski Indeed you both are right. Using ```double``` closes the gap. And when I calculate the ```FLOP``` for the determinant calculation I get an insane high number.